# How to identify if a property has specified value in second property in a JSON using java script through loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON array as below, now from this JSON array I need to identify if a property has a specified value in another property, for example

```
[{
  "checkType": "Education 1",
  "docType": "Others"
}, {
  "checkType": "Education 1",
  "docType": "Fellowship Certificate"
}, {
  "checkType": "Personal",
  "docType": "Passport copy"
}]
```

I need to store message in a variable if the the check type has only one docType as others, if check type has doctype other than "Others" than i dont need to store the message in variable. And this all i want to achieve through code not some predefined function.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please add what your expected result would be given the example data-set.  It sounds like you'll need to use either Array.filter or Array.find depending on whether you want all items which meet your criteria, or just the first one.

Comment: the question is for example if the json has check type only once as education and doc type as "Others" than I will put a console.log saying "Others found", end if the json has several check type as education and doc type as "Others"  and some other doctypes also than no log.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
let data = [{
      "checkType": "Education 1",
      "docType": "Others"
     }, {
      "checkType": "Education 1",
      "docType": "Fellowship Certificate"
     }, {
      "checkType": "Personal",
      "docType": "Passport copy"
    }]

let messages = data.filter((val) => val.docType === 'Others').map((val) => val.checkType);
```

Answer (score -1):

This will check for the an item in the array that has a `docType` of "Others", so long as there is no other item with the same `checkType` but a different `docType`:

```
if (data.find(item => (item.docType === "Others") &&
    !data.find(other => (other.checkType === item.checkType) && (other.docType !== "Others")))) {
    console.log("Others found");
}
```

Comment: is there not a way to achieve this without the find method, i mean only use loops and if else conditions ?

Comment: Of course; the `Array.find` method internally iterates through the array using a standard `for` loop and runs the predicate against each item.  The first one that returns true is the result of the function.  In this case though there is no real benefit to not using the Array methods, other than the definition of the predicate.